# problem with event handlers in dojo

Tags: javascript, html, dojo

I have a  span inside which i have a achor tag.For anchor tag , i have used DojoAttachEvent,Now somwhere  in my code i replace innerHTML of span  as show below.

```
<span id ="xyz"> <a dojoAttachEvent="onmouseover:_myfunction"> txt223 </a> </span>
```

Now i replace text of span as follows:

```
var tmptxt = dojo.byId("xyz").innerHTML
dojo.byId("xyz").innerHTML = "some more txt" +tmptxt
```

Now after running this code the function _myfunction doesnot get called when onmoveover gets triggered.

I know that i can  get away with the problem by using two spans ,one for next txt and one for anchor , but due to some  css issues(i get each span on new line,its some two colum css and if i use 2 spans txt and anchor come on 2 different line which we dont want) i cant do it.

I tried to use dojo.connect , but the problem is as my span is  present in some wizard the event gets triggered when am on page other then the page which is the current page of wizard.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.it may helps.

```
<span id ="xyz"> <a dojoAttachEvent="onmouseover:_myfunction();return true;"> txt223 </a> </span>
```

Comment: thanks for answer, i will try it.But i have one question.since dojo parses the page on page load , it will make a hitch .But if at run time i am trying to replace that span with its innerHTML it will cause the issue i guess

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if this isn't inside a widget template, `dojoAttachEvent` isn't what you want - you probably want something more like `onMouseOver="_myfunction();"`.

Secondly, if you're replacing the innerHTML of the *parent* node of the node in question with the event, then naturally you're going to end up clobbering that node out of existence, and the event along with it, and you'd have to hook it up again one way or another.  Is there a reason you can't be more careful with your DOM manipulation?  Like, put an id on the `a` tag (or query for it from the `span`) and change only that node's innerHTML?